# solve the integral $\iint(7+2y-x)\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$ bounded by $x+y=1$ and $x^2+y=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Clearly this is a type I integral $\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$ integrating the other way would be a lot of work I don't want radicals my upper bound on y is $y=x-1$ and lower bound on y is $y=1-x^2$ and setting them equal to get $x$-values gives me $x=0$ or $x=1$.

So setting it up gives me:

$$\int_0^1\Big[\int_{1-x^2}^{1-x} 7+2y-x \mathrm{d}y\Big] \mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int_0^1\Big[\int 7y+y^2-xy\Big]\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int_0^1\Big[7(1-x)+(1-x)^2-x(1-x)- 7(1-x^2)+(1-x^2)^2-x(1-x^2)\Big]\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int_0^1 \Big[7-7x+x^2-2x+1-x+x^2-7+7x^2-x^4+2x^2-1+x^3\Big]\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int_0^1 11x^2-10x-x^4+x^3 \mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\frac{11x^3}{3}-5x^2-\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^4}{4} \Big\vert_0^1$$

$$=\frac{11}{3}-5-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{4}$$

For some reason I just can't get the correct answer even though Integrating this is not hard some stupid %$##@ arithmetic error keeps getting in the way.

Comment: The third line has incorrect signs. It should be $$\int_0^1\Big[7(1-x)+(1-x)^2-x(1-x)- 7(1-x^2)-(1-x^2)^2+x(1-x^2)\Big]\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: And there is the hidden error in the fourh line, $$\int_0^1 \Big[7-7x+x^2-2x+1-x+x^2-7+7x^2-x^4+2x^2-\bbox[yellow]{1}+x^3\Big]dx$$ which must be $$\int_0^1 \Big[7-7x+x^2-2x+1-x+x^2-7+7x^2-x^4+2x^2-\bbox[yellow]{x}+x^3\Big]dx$$

Answer (score 1):

The inner integral in the first line is wrong:
$$\int_{1-x^2}^{1-x} 7+2y-x \ \mathrm{d}y.$$
Take a look at the following figure to see why:

[image]

So, the right version is

$$\int_{1-x}^{1-x^2} 7+2y-x \ \mathrm{d}y.$$
(There are further sign errors in the third line...)